# JSP/JSTL - How to loop through a list within a list?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm just starting to learn JSTL so I may be missing something obvious but how do you loop through a list that get through the ArrayList .get() method. I need to iterate through using a counter maybe i.e. .get(i).

JSP Code:

```
<c:forEach items="${processVariablesList}" var="customerHistoryVariables">
    <c:forEach items="${processVariablesList.get(0)}" var="variable">
        <li><strong>${variable.getName()}: </strong>${variable.getValue()}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Servlet Code:

```
ArrayList<List<HistoricVariableInstance>> processVariablesList = new ArrayList<List<HistoricVariableInstance>>();

            for(int i = 0;i<processList.size();i++){

                String processId = processList.get(i).getId();

                List<HistoricVariableInstance> variableList = historyService.createHistoricVariableInstanceQuery()
                        .processInstanceId(processId).list();

                processVariablesList.add(variableList);

            }
```

Comment: You need to access only the first element of the inner list ?

Comment: No, the code I have up there is what I've got working so far but I want to iterate through like you would in a for loop i.e. int i = 0, i++, .get(i). I just don't no how to achieve this  with jstl.

Comment: The same way as you iterate the outer loop. Use the outer loop variable in the items of the inner loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ty this:

```
<c:forEach items="${processVariablesList}" var="customerHistoryVariables">
    <c:forEach items="${customerHistoryVariables}" var="variable">
         <li><strong>${variable.getName()}: </strong>${variable.getValue()}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yep, this works. I can't believe I didn't get this before. Thanks.